# Android: Get the return value from an AsyncTask without blocking the UI thread

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Inside the `onCreate` of an `Activity` I do the following:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
    AsyncTask<String, Integer, String[]> asynctask = new DownloadFilesTask(this.getActivity()).execute(url);
    String[] values = null;         
    try {
        values = asynctask.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {          
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d("AsyncTask", "DONE!");        
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

This works but I am blocking the UI thread with `asynctask.get();` which stops me from showing any new UI elements like a dialog during the background task that it performs.

So my question: How do I get the result value from my AsyncTask without blocking the UI thread given this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

move this to `onPostExecute`:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);

setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: You had the most straightforward answer. It works now thanks!

Comment: When using AsyncTasks, be sure to account for the case where the user has navigated away and your UI is dead when postExecute is called.

Answer (score 1):

[`get()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29) is designed to be called from inside [`onPostExecute(Result result)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29). Basically the latter is executed on the UI thread just after [`doInBackground()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29) is finished or throws exception.

For Example:

```
class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>
{
    @Override
    public Result doInBackground(Params... params)
    {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Result result)
    {
        try
        {
            Result result = get();

            // we are fine here, do something with the result
        }
        catch(CancellationException e){/* if cancel() is called on this instance */}
        catch(ExecutionException e){/* if doInBackground() throws some exception */}
        catch(InterruptedException e){/* If the current thread was interrupted while waiting */}
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:** I must be confused with [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) :\

After [`doInBackground()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29) is finished, [`onPostExecute(Result result)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) is executed on the UI thread with having the result passed from [`doInBackground()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29) as a method parameter.

```
class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>
{
    @Override
    public Result doInBackground(Params... params)
    {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Result result)
    {
        // do something with the result
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually no, it  is not, since in onPostExecute you have result in(suprise!) result variable... get() is for forcing not async behavior...

Comment: @Selvin What do you mean? Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @Selvin You are right, I must be confused with [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).

Answer (score 0):

1- Could you post also DownloadFilesTask?

2- When asyncTask executes, it's not gonna loaded or whatever you're doing, that's not gonna happen immediately, right? So just after you call asynctask you may not be able to get results from it... So i would suggest you to use onPostExecute method of asyncTask